# angular not 2-way binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Trying to teach myself AngularJS and am stuck on a tutorial trying to build a simple shopping cart. I cannot for the life of me figure out why my {{}} angular tags are not displaying the data in the view, rather they are displaying the literal string (i.e. {{item.price | currency}}) Any insights? I'm worried the code isn't referencing the angular library, but the source is correct - the library is saved as angular.min.js .

Please help!

`

```
<html ng-app='myApp'>
<head>
    <title>Your Shopping Cart </title>
</head>
<body ng-controller='CartController'>
    <h1> Your order</h1>
    <div ng-repeat='item in items'>
        <span>{{item.title}}</span>
        <input ng-model='item.quantity'>
        <span>{{item.price | currency}}</span>
        <span>{{item.price * item.quantity | currency}}</span>
        <button ng-click="remove($index)">Remove</button>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function CartController($scope){
            $scope.items = [
                {title: 'Paint pots', quantity: 8, price: 3.95},
                {title: 'Polka dots', quantity: 17, price: 12.95},
                {title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 5, price: 6.95}
            ];

            $scope.remove = function(index){
                $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: any console errors?, if using chrome pres f12 and look for any errors in console

Comment: As bto.rdz asked. Please look for error in chrome debugger. I would say you have not define your Angular app module, while you are calling ng-app='myApp' at top. Trying putting only "ng-app" and see if the problem is solved.

Comment: Seems to be working fine here http://plnkr.co/edit/Em4KhNGa4f7zGwcbm1B4?p=preview

Comment: global controller functions are not supported anymore in v1.3 of angular. XrXrXr is correct. Register your controller function instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set a value to `ng-app` (like `ng-app="MyApp"`), Angular.JS will expect you to have something like `var myModule = angular.module("MyApp", [])`.

It will look for controllers only inside that, using `myModule.controller()` method (or can be directly after the module call). A global function will not work.

So, you have 2 options:

1. Replace `<html ng-app="MyApp">` with `<html ng-app>`
2. Creating a module:

   ```
   angular.module("MyApp", []).controller("CartController", function($scope) {
       /// ...
   });
   ```

Note that if you are using **Angular.JS 1.3**, you have to use method 2, as the global scope function way was removed in that version.

Comment: I am using 1.2.23. I changed <html ng-app="MyApp> and it worked! I am confused as to why it didn't work initially. Any idea what is wrong with their code or if I missed something?

Comment: Another answer here suggested a particular book mentioned that it will not initialise the app in every example. This might be the reason

Answer (score 1):

It is because `CartController` is just a plain function. You have to add it as a controller under the `myApp` module

```
angular.module("maApp", []).
controller("CartController", function ($scope) {
        $scope.items = [
            {title: 'Paint pots', quantity: 8, price: 3.95},
            {title: 'Polka dots', quantity: 17, price: 12.95},
            {title: 'Pebbles', quantity: 5, price: 6.95}
        ];

        $scope.remove = function(index){
            $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
        }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying this example from Angularjs Book, in which they have clearly mentioned that we are not initializing app for every example, you need to initialize your app. or simply ignore app, start coding from controller. when you mention ng-app="sample" you need to bootstrap that in order to work with controllers directives and everything that you use. In case if you dont want to initialize then you can simply leave ng-app="" blank. Here is working example [fiddle][1]

```
 [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/kaLropns/
```